# xpath get text and anchors between br tags

Tags: php, html, xpath

I have a, for me, very hard question:

this is the HTML I'm dealing with:

```
<td>
Margaret (Parky) DeVogelaere
(<a href="/date/06-19?ref_=nmbio_sp_1">19 June</a>&nbsp;
2011 - 
<a href="/date/08-16?ref_=nmbio_sp_1">16 August</a>&nbsp;
2019)&nbsp;(his death)
<br/>
Portia Rebecca "Becky" Crockett
(<a href="/date/11-11?ref_=nmbio_sp_2">11 November</a>&nbsp;
1975                            - 
2011)&nbsp;(divorced)
<br/>
<a href="/name/nm0108232?ref_=nmbio_sp_3">Susan Brewer </a>(<a href="/date/10-08?ref_=nmbio_sp_3">8 October</a>&nbsp;
1961                            - 
<a href="/date/04-15?ref_=nmbio_sp_3">15 April</a>&nbsp;
1974)&nbsp;(divorced)
&nbsp;(2 children)
</td>
```

How do i get with xpath everything, including anchor between the start of td and first br/ and repeat that for everything between the first br/ and the next one? and so on.
I hope i make myself clear and I'm not a professional, just a hobby programmer

NodeValue just gives all of the text but not the href from a possible person anchor, witch is not always the case as you can see

So to make it more clear this is what i want:

```
Margaret (Parky) DeVogelaere (<a href="/date/06-19?ref_=nmbio_sp_1">19
June</a>&nbsp; 2011 -  <a href="/date/08-16?ref_=nmbio_sp_1">16
August</a>&nbsp; 2019)&nbsp;(his death)

Portia Rebecca "Becky" Crockett
(<a href="/date/11-11?ref_=nmbio_sp_2">11 November</a>&nbsp;
1975                            - 
2011)&nbsp;(divorced)

<a href="/name/nm0108232?ref_=nmbio_sp_3">Susan Brewer </a>(<a href="/date/10-08?ref_=nmbio_sp_3">8 October</a>&nbsp;
1961                            - 
<a href="/date/04-15?ref_=nmbio_sp_3">15 April</a>&nbsp;
1974)&nbsp;(divorced)
&nbsp;(2 children)
```

This comes from imdb https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0001228/bio Family, spouse part

I can get the td in question, but don't understand how i get the data that i want

```
$cells = $xp->query("//table[contains(@id, 'tableFamily')]/tr[1]/td[2]")
```

Or does anybody know a different approach?

Answer (score 0):

Well, your html is a litlle funky, so one way to get what you want (or close to it) is to perform some surgery on the original HTML (replacing the `<br/>`s with `</td><td>`s so as to create parsable elements, and then use an HTML parser and xpath:

```
$orig = '
[your html above]
';
$newstring = str_replace("<br/>", "</td><td>", $orig);
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($newstring);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$sources = $xpath->query('//td');
foreach ($sources as $source) {
    echo $source->ownerDocument->saveHTML($source)."\r\n---------------\r\n";
};
```

Output:

```
<td>
Margaret (Parky) DeVogelaere
(<a href="/date/06-19?ref_=nmbio_sp_1">19 June</a> 
2011 - 
<a href="/date/08-16?ref_=nmbio_sp_1">16 August</a> 
2019) (his death)
</td>
---------------
<td>
Portia Rebecca "Becky" Crockett
(<a href="/date/11-11?ref_=nmbio_sp_2">11 November</a> 
1975                            - 
2011) (divorced)
</td>
---------------
<td>
<a href="/name/nm0108232?ref_=nmbio_sp_3">Susan Brewer </a>(<a href="/date/10-08?ref_=nmbio_sp_3">8 October</a> 
1961                            - 
<a href="/date/04-15?ref_=nmbio_sp_3">15 April</a> 
1974) (divorced)
 (2 children)
</td>
---------------
```

Comment: Thanks for looking in to this.
your example got me thinking, i used saveHTML on the td and explode() on br tag. that worked!
Funny thing is that in the page source the break character is br / but if i inspect this element in Firefox it states only br. explode works on br but not br /